# how to sort element from a vector in c?

Tags: c

I write a program that calculates the average of several students and stores them in a table. After he sorts the elements of this array and displays each in ascending order.
I write the function for sorting and the one that calculates student averages but I do not know why it does not work.
that's my function

```
void triage(float tableau [], int taile){
int temp = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < taile - 1; i++){
    if(tableau[i] > tableau [i+1]){
        temp = tableau[i];
        tableau [i] = tableau[i+1];
        tableau [i+1] = temp;
        temp = 0;
    }
    }
}

void classementEtudiants(){
int note = 0, somme = 0, sommeTotal = 0;
float moyenne = 0, moyenneTotal[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < e.etude[i].nbCours; i++){
                float not1 = e.etude[i].coursPris.TC[j].examenPartiel;
                float not2 = e.etude[i].coursPris.TC[j].examenFinal;
                somme = not1 + not2;
                moyenne = somme / 2;
                sommeTotal = sommeTotal + moyenne;
            }
            moyenneTotal[i] = sommeTotal / e.etude[i].nbCours;

            triage(moyenneTotal,n);
            printf("Classement des etudiants par ordre de merite \n");
            for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
                printf("\t\t %d(e) %s %s avec une moyenne generale de %f \n", k,e.etude[i].nom,e.etude[i].prenom, moyenneTotal[k]);
            }
    }
}
```

void triage is the function that's making sorting ang void classement is the one who class those different elements

Comment: First please learn how to *debug* your programs, which is the normal way to fix problems likes you probably have. With a *debugger* you can step through the code, statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values. This makes it easy to see if and when something goes wrong. Once you've debugged your code and fixed the problems with it, then learn about [the standard C `qsort` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) and use it for your sorting instead.

Comment: @JrMbh7 This function  triage sorts nothing. And it is unclear where the variable n is defined. You can use the standard C function qsort if you are unable to write the bubble sort yourself.

Comment: A possible hint though: `float tableau []` and `int temp` and `temp = tableau[i]`... Pay close attention to the *types*.

Comment: But also pay attention to algorithm.  `triage` performs one pass of Bubble Sort, but that is not ordinarily enough to completely sort the input.  That is, the algorithm is not completely implemented.

Comment: thanks for all these suggestions